# VS Code Extensions API undocumented function "exports.deactivate"

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

When using the Yeoman Extension Generator, `yo code` to initialize an extension, it creates an exported function called `deactivate()`. I want to implement this for my extension to clean up when it is deactivated or disabled, but I don't know if it takes an extension context like the `activate(context)` export.

I can't find any uses for the function in example extensions or the [relevant documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/vscode-api#Extension).

If anyone knows how this function is used or what arguments are passed to it, when it is called, please let me know, and maybe we should update the documentation to include this export.

Answer (score 0):

No, the `deactivate()` function has no parameters at all. And to be honest, I'm not sure if this function is called at all. At least I have no code there and I have seen quite a number of extensions that either don't implement it at all or just have an empty body.

Comment: I figured out that it does get called when Visual Studio Code is closed. I would assume it also gets called when the extension is disabled or uninstalled. But I don't understand why it's undocumented.